# How to create a matrix dynamically in R?

Tags: r

I need to generate a logical matrix in R. The dimension of the matrix is dynamic, both column names and row names of the matrix come from vectors.

```
vector1 <- c(a,b,c,d)
vector2 <- c(a,c,e,f,g)
vector3 <- c(d,f,g,z)
```

and so on...

It iterates each vectors, set the vector name as row name. If the vector value is found in matrix column name, set the corresponding matrix cell value to be 1, otherwise add a new column to the matrix and assign value 1 to the cell. 
The matrix values are either 1/0, it should work like this

```
        a  b  c  d  e  f  g  z
vector1 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
vector2 1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
vector3 0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1
```

It's just a simple demo, actually the size of each vector is very large.

Comment: Do you have all the vectors at the start, or do you need to create a matrix for some vectors, then add more one by one?

Comment: It would be good if you could *at least* (1) post valid code, (2) format your code and data properly, and ideally (3) show us what you’ve tried.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the original post it in a rush. I've tried multiple ways, but got stuck in adding new columns/rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
#DATA
vector1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
vector2 = c("a", "c", "e", "f", "g")
vector3 = c("d", "f", "g", "z")

#Get all vectors in a list
temp = mget(paste("vector", 1:3, sep = ""))
           #You could do sequence(length(ls(pattern = "vector"))) instead of 1:3

#1) As pointed out in the comments by akrun, use `mtabulate` of `qdapTools` package
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(temp)
#        a b c d e f g z
#vector1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#vector2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
#vector3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

#2) Or if you want to do it in base R

  #2-i) as pointed out by akrun
  table(stack(temp)[2:1]) #also check data.frame(unclass(table(stack(temp)[2:1])))
  #         values
  #ind       a b c d e f g z
  #  vector1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  #  vector2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
  #  vector3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

  #2-ii)
  #Get the unique values
  temp2 = unique(unlist(temp))

  setNames(object = data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(a)
      as.numeric(temp2 %in% a)))),
      nm = temp2)
  #        a b c d e f g z
  #vector1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  #vector2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
  #vector3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Or this can be done more compactly `qdapTools::mtabulate(temp)` or with `base R` i.e. `table(stack(temp)[2:1])`

Comment: It's okay.  You can add it in your post.as you also helped me sometimes with your generosity :-)

Comment: Fwiw, I think the original `table(stack(temp)[2:1])` is better than `t(table(stack(temp)))`. Re `2-ii`, if a data.frame is desired, there's also as.data.frame(unclass(z)) where z is the table-stack output.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Although being late to the party, I would like to suggest two different approaches concerning

- storing and reading of the dynamic, "sparse matrix" information
- and creating the matrix using `dcast()`.

#### Storing and reading the dynamic matrix information

The OP has disclosed that *both column names and row names of the matrix come from vectors* and that *actually the size of each vector is very large*. She has given sample data

```
vector1 <- c(a,b,c,d)
vector2 <- c(a,c,e,f,g)
vector3 <- c(d,f,g,z)
```

where the column names are  **no valid character strings**. Each of the column names need to be wrapped in quotes (as done [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620621/3817004)) which would be tedious for large vectors.

Therefore, I suggest to store row names `rn` and column names `cn` of the matrix in a compact and handy form:

```
rn      cn
vector1 a,b,c,d
vector2 a,c,e,f,g
vector3 d,f,g,z
```

either in a file or in a character string. `cn` contains the names of the matrix columns separated by comma.

This "sparse matrix definition" can be read, e.g.,

```
library(data.table)
sparse <- fread("
rn      cn
vector1 a,b,c,d
vector2 a,c,e,f,g
vector3 d,f,g,z
")
```

#### Creating the matrix

This requires two steps. First, the column names needs to be extracted for each row name. This is accomplished by using `strsplit()`:

```
long <- sparse[, strsplit(cn, ","), by = rn]

long
#         rn V1
# 1: vector1  a
# 2: vector1  b
# 3: vector1  c
# 4: vector1  d
# 5: vector2  a
# 6: vector2  c
# 7: vector2  e
# 8: vector2  f
# 9: vector2  g
#10: vector3  d
#11: vector3  f
#12: vector3  g
#13: vector3  z
```

This returns the sparse matrix information in *long format*. Note that `V1` now contains the names of the matrix columns as character saving us from wrapping them in quotes manually.

Now, the OP is expecting the result in *wide format* with `0` or `1` indicating absence or presence of the respective column. The reshape can be accomplished using `dcast()`:

```
result <- dcast(long, rn ~ V1, length)

result
#        rn a b c d e f g z
#1: vector1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#2: vector2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
#3: vector3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Or, in a more convoluted form:

```
result <- dcast(sparse[, strsplit(cn, ","), by = rn], rn ~ V1, length)
```

Now, the result can be converted from `data.table` into a matrix with appropriate row names:

```
mat <- as.matrix(result[, .SD, .SDcols = -c("rn")])
rownames(mat) <- result[, rn]
mat
#        a b c d e f g z
#vector1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#vector2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
#vector3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```